# How do I upsert a MongoDB document only in certain circumstances?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update a user-document in a MongoDB collection. If the user doesn't exist it should be created, but if it already exist it should only be updated given the query parses certain checks.

This is what I first tried:

```
var ts = new Date('2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
var query = { name: 'bob', updatedAt: { $lt: ts } };
var update = { $set: { age: 42, updatedAt: ts }, $inc: { updates: 1 } };
db.users.update(query, update, { upsert: true });
```

The problem with that solution is that it will try to create the user twice if its `updatedAt` property is less than the given `ts` date.

How can I make sure it's created only if the `name` part of the query doesn't match any documents, but don't do anything if the `updatedAt` part doesn't?

Comment: you mean *create use if  `updatedAt` greater than `ts`*

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure I completely understand your comment, but I only want to update the document if the `updatedAt` date is less than the provided date (i.e. if the stored document contains older data than the data I'm trying to update it with). If the document in the database is newer than the date I test against I do not want to update it

Comment: @Michael if you by "new document" mean a "duplicate" document, then you are unfortunately wrong (at least on Mongo 2.6.5). It will create a new user if the `updatedAt` part of the query doesn't match any document. Even if a user with the `name` "bob" already exists :(

Comment: @Michael I've created a gist where you can see what happens when I run it: https://gist.github.com/watson/9d2be3b181d38f86119d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically:

- The user does not exists, create it with the current time as the "last update time". This could be done using a simple `upset` and [`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/);
- The user already exists *and* need to be updated. This is a simple `update`.

Simply said, you need two update *statements*. But, you may wrap them in the same [update command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/update/#dbcmd.update):

```
db.runCommand({
  update: 'users',
  updates: [
    { q: { name: 'bob' },
      u: { $setOnInsert: { updatedAt: now, updates: 0 }},
      upsert: true },
    { q: { name: 'bob', updatedAt: { $lt: now } },
      u: { $set: { updatedAt: now }, $inc: { updates: 1 } },
      upsert: false },
  ]
})
```

Producing on the first run (empty collection):

```
> var now = new Date()
> db.runCommand({   update: 'users',   updates: [     { q: { name: 'bob' },       u: { $setOnInsert: { updatedAt: now, updates: 0 }},       upsert: true },     { q: { name: 'bob', updatedAt: { $lt: now } },       u: { $set: { updatedAt: now }, $inc: { updates: 1 } },       upsert: false },   ] })
{
    "ok" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "n" : 1,
    "upserted" : [
        {
            "index" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("556f672cd418ed1506eb2ca3")
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, when run again:

```
> var now = new Date()
> db.runCommand({   update: 'users',   updates: [     { q: { name: 'bob' },       u: { $setOnInsert: { updatedAt: now, updates: 0 }},       upsert: true },     { q: { name: 'bob', updatedAt: { $lt: now } },       u: { $set: { updatedAt: now }, $inc: { updates: 1 } },       upsert: false },   ] })
{ "ok" : 1, "nModified" : 1, "n" : 2 }
```

Please note that the update *command* is not atomic. But there is no way for an other client to see a partially created or updated user document as either the first update statement *create* the fully populated document, or it already exists (and is left untouched) until the second statement that updates it completely.

It is even safe if the user is concurrently created *between* the two statements -- it will then be transparently updated if needed.